# $r$-separated sequence in Hilbert spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying (with no good results) to prove the follwing:

**Prop.** Let $B^1\subset H$ be the unit ball in the Hilbert space $H$. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset B^1$ is a $r$-separated sequence, i.e. $\vert\vert x_j-x_k\vert\vert\geq r$, for any $j\neq k$, then $r\leq \sqrt{2}$.

Can you help me to prove the reult above?

Comment: What bad results do you have? We need to see some sort of attempt///

Comment: Many thanks. I think we can close the question.